# Pasar datos del datagrid de un formulario a textbox de otro formulario wpf

Tags: sql, vb.net, wpf, xaml

Tengo el siguiente código para cargar mis datos en un datagrid de un formulario:

```
Private Sub cargarGrid()
    Dim conexion As New ConexionBD
    Dim data As DataTable
    dataGridVehiculos.ItemsSource = Nothing
    Try
        data = conexion.mostrarDatosenGrid("VEHICULOS_EN_TRANSITO")
        dataGridVehiculos.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function mostrarDatosenGrid(ByVal tabla As String) As DataTable
        Dim nuevaTabla As New DataTable
        Try
            conexion()
            _adaptador.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & tabla, _conexion)
            _conexion.Open()
            _adaptador.SelectCommand.Connection = _conexion
            _adaptador.Fill(nuevaTabla)
            Return nuevaTabla
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            _conexion.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Me funciona para cargar los datos en el data grid, lo que no me a funcionado es que al seleccionar un ítem del data grid no me carga en el texbox de otro formulario tengo el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub dataGridVehiculos_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles dataGridVehiculos.SelectionChanged
    Dim tabla As DataRowView = DirectCast(dataGridVehiculos.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    registro.noTiquete = tabla.Item(1)
    registro.fechaPesoVacio = tabla.Item(2)
    registro.fechaPesoLleno = tabla.Item(3)
    registro.placa = tabla(4)
    registro.conductor.cedula = tabla.Item(5)
    registro.conductor.nombre = tabla.Item(6)
    registro.clienteProveedor.nombre = tabla.Item(7)
    registro.productoMateriaPrima.nombre = tabla.Item(8)
    registro.tara = tabla.Item(9)
    registro.bruto = tabla.Item(10)
    registro.neto = tabla.Item(11)
    registro.noOrden = tabla.Item(12)
    registro.origen.nombre = tabla.Item(13)
    registro.destino.nombre = tabla.Item(14)
    registro.observaciones = tabla.Item(15)
    registro.taraAutorizado = tabla.Item(16)
    registro.brutoAturorizado = tabla.Item(17)
    registro.usuarioTransito = tabla.Item(18)
    registro.usuarioProcesado = tabla.Item(19)
    registro.rutaFotos = tabla.Item(20)
    registro.horaPesoVacio = tabla.Item(21)
    registro.horaPesoVacio = tabla.Item(22)
    registro.noShipment = tabla.Item(23)
    registro.noSello = tabla.Item(24)
    registro.noR = tabla.Item(25)
    registro.noContenedor = tabla.Item(26)
    registro.planta.nombre = tabla.Item(28)
    registro.transportadora.nombre = tabla.Item(29)
    registro.pesoOrden = tabla.Item(30)
End Sub
```

No he podido saber que estoy haciendo mal, o si debo hacerlo de otra forma, la clase registro es una clase que contiene los campos necesarios para almacenar los datos del grid y desde allí poder llevar esa información a los texbox, el punto es que los datos no están pasando del grid a los campos de la clase, alguien podría darme una mano para saber exactamente como hacerlo? este el código xaml.

```
<DataGrid Margin="-351.935,-15.119,-355.73,-61.323" ItemsSource="{Binding Items3}" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  md:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8" md:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8"></DataGrid>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una observación de partida:

El DataGrid tiene definido el ItemSource mediante Binding pero se lo estás asignando en el código también, como tu código no está definido como MVVM no necesitas el Binding.

Lo otro que es sobre tu pregunta, usa el modo de selección FullRow y cuando selecciones algo obtén el SelectedItem y de ese objeto que resulta toma el ItemArray que es el objeto que contiene todas las columnas de la fila y esa la podrías recorrer o usar el index de la celda que seleccionaste para obtener ese dato específico:

```
DataRowView view = (DataRowView)myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
int index = dg_detail.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
string cellvalue = view.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
```

Disculpa que lo escriba en C#, no manejo bien Vb.